# Have several emails and reminders unsnoozed together in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

Very often, a real-world task involves a number of different email threads and, especially in the case of Google Inbox, reminders. In Google Inbox, items can be snoozed until a later date, at which they magically reappear in your inbox. If a snoozed email receives a response before the snooze date, it is unsnoozed. Unfortunately, the items that I snoozed with that email are not unsnoozed, so I kind of lose track of which items belong together.
(As a workaround, note that Google Inbox offers to re-snooze an unsnoozed email to the original snooze date, which is displayed. So I then go to "Snoozed", scroll to that date, and manually unsnooze the items by pinning them. Not ideal, though.)

I am looking for a way to snooze items together (this works) *and have them unsnoozed* together.

I have tried bundles, but you [cannot snooze a bundle](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/-FlVh-6TbdI).

What other ways are there to group items to have them unsnoozed together?

Comment: This may be a feature request. I personally group tasks into a single reminder--either tied to an email or not. Something like: `Finish planning party: see emails with Jim and Mary`. You could also create folders on the fly, i.e. `Party Planning` and put in the emails from Jim and Mary. And then create a reminder that says `Finish "Party Planning"`. 

In your case, I suppose you could also add a reminder to every email related to party planning that says "Party Planning" and then you'll know to search for all other emails `is:reminder "party planning"`.

Comment: @JBallin Regarding the latter, I have tried that. For some reason, though, Google Inbox does not find (any? all?) email threads that contain your search phrase only in the reminder part, regardless of whether or not I am using `is:reminder`. I have yet to understand why that is the case, it would help a lot if it just did that.

Comment: Agree there should be a way to search reminder text specifically but maybe you could make unique names such as ‘Party Planning 3.5.18’? As you probably know, is:reminder filters emails that only have a reminder attached to them

Comment: @JBallin I think I did not express myself clearly enough. My concern is not that Inbox returns *too many* results because it includes emails with reminders whose email body matches (it does), and not just emails with reminders whose reminder matches. This is about Inbox returning *too few* results, by not returning emails with reminders where *only the reminder* matches. Try it: When I have an email in Google Inbox, and I add the reminder "xyz123abc" to it (or any word *not* in the email body), both the search for `is:reminder xyz123abc` and the search for `xyz123abc` return "No results".

Comment: @JBallin in short, "there should be a way to search reminder text s̶p̶e̶c̶i̶f̶i̶c̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ **at all**". I have offloaded this issue to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114976/

Comment: Sorry for the misinformation! I hope I helped brainstorm regardless. I guess I would just put them into folders by project. But I can understand wanting something more automated. You could also consider looking into other email services with more advanced features. Good luck!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.